# Synchronous calls in akka / actor model

Tags: actor, akka

I've been looking into Akka lately and it looks like a great framework for building scalable servers on the JVM. However most of the libraries on the JVM are blocking (e.g. JDBC) so don't your lose out on the performance benefits of using an event based model because your threads will always be blocked? Does Akka do something to get around this? Or is it just something you have to live with until we get more non-blocking libraries on the JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at CQRS, it greatly improves scalability by separating reads from writes. This means that you can scale your reads separately from your writes.

Answer (score 0):

With the types of IO blocking issues you mentioned Scala provides a language embedded solution that matches perfectly: [Futures](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future).  For example:

```
def expensiveDBQuery(key : Key) = Future {
  //...query the database 
}

val dbResult : Future[Result] = 
  expensiveDBQuery(...) //non-blocking call
```

The dbResult returns immediately from the function call.  The Result will be a available in the "`Future`".  The cool part about a Future is that you can think about them like any old collection, except you can never call `.size` on the Future.  Other than that all collection-ish functions (e.g. `map`, `filter`, `foreach`, ...) are fair game.  Simply think of the dbResult as a list of Results.  What would you do with such a list:

```
dbResult.map(_.getValues)
        .filter(values => someTestOnValues(values))
        ...
```

That sequence of calls sets up a computation pipeline that is invoked whenever the Result is actually returned from the database.  You can give a sequence of computing steps before the data has arrived.  All asynchronously.